# Angular - My function is running in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a menu that allow some users to have access to some content:

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/local" >Local</a></li>
      <li><a href="/fazenda" ng-class = "{botaodisabled:botoes('Fazenda')}">Fazenda</a></li>
      <li><a href="/gleba">Gleba</a></li>
```

In this sample `'Fazenda'` will check if the user will be to have access beyond the function `botoes('Fazenda')`. In the end all the items of the menu will get this function to check if the user has access to it. The problem is that my function doesn't run once for each item of the menu, creating an infinite loop.

Angular:

```
$scope.botoes = function(nome) {   
        console.log(nome);           
        $http.get('/botaopermissao/'+nome).success(function(data) {     
            console.log(data);       

            if(data == "Encontrado!"){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `$http.get` is async, you must use a function that return true/false immediately. Not to mention that you cant return anything from async request

Comment: This will be triggered **every** digest cycle!! Don't do this!! Just create a `$scope` property that you initialize in the controller

Comment: also, the use of `.success()` is deprecated, you should use `.then()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function(nome) {   
    console.log(nome);           
    $http.get('/botaopermissao/'+nome).success(function(data) {     
        console.log(data);       

        if(data == "Encontrado!"){
            $scope.botoa= "what you want";
        }
        }
    });
}
```

Because your method is triggered at every cycle which can cause an infinite iteration, so it will be better to use scope inside your controller.